# CakePHP Increase Year Range in Drop Down

Tags: cakephp, date, range

In CakePHP, if i keep a table field type as `date`, then it shows dropdown with month, day and year. However, the year range starts from `1990` only, how can I change it to start from `1900`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `minYear` and `maxYear` options of an input like this:

```
<?php

echo $this->Form->input('birth_dt', array(
    'label' => 'Date of birth', 
    'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
    'minYear' => date('Y') - 70,
    'maxYear' => date('Y') - 18 ));

?>
```

Reference to cakePHP [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-form-elements)

FYI: If current year is 2017 date('Y') - 70 will be 1947 [2017 - 70 = 1947].

Comment: this is not working for me in cakephp 3. Any solution?
I have read the docs from [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-datetime-controls) and tried copy pasting one of the dateTime fields but all in vain.