# CakePHP 3.0.6 Increase Year Range in Drop Down

Tags: php, date, cakephp

In CakePHP 3.0.6, if I keep a table field type as date, then it shows dropdown with month, day and year.

However, the year range starts from 2010 only. How can I change it to start from 1900 or any year for that matter?

I'm fairly new to CakePHP and I'm actually studying it from the ground up so if anybody could give me a detailed suggestion on how to do it, like what controllers, models, or views to add or edit, I will really be grateful as it will help me understand how things work. If it will help: The name of the table is `rosters` and the field is `Birthdate`.

By the way this question was already asked before; in fact I copied the exact title and just added the CakePHP version.

Comment: Yes indeed. However, as pointed out:1. The answer in the question doesn't say what file or part of the framework needs to be changed/edited/added the code to (ie, is it the model, controller, or view ) 2.  I'm asking this cause I still don't quite know how Cake actually work, as opposed to if I'm already familiar then I would certainly know where to implement the answer in my code. (The answer looks good by the way, but I'm not sure if it will work as I don't know and hence haven't implemented it) 3.  I've specified the the cake version. Diff cake version have diff. file/directory structures.

Comment: @AnthonyNavasca the answer indicates that you need to use the code in your view ( .ctp file). And i would suggest you to read the docs prior to actually starting to work on cakePHP, as without proper knowledge of how the framework works will lead you to various kinds of problems, like the current one. So read the docs.

Comment: Yay Thanks! Thanks for the answer and the advice. I tried it and modified it for the add.ctp and it worked! I'm actually reading documents right now, (page/ step-by step if i may say. I'm reading Apress: Beginning Cake Php, from beginner to novice, obviously am lower than a noob hahaha! anyway the doc is from 2008 but it's really helpful. The problem is it uses a diff. version and hence rules, folder structure, you get the idea. Also , I like learning things by doing and tweaking them as I do so that's why. Anyway thanks,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As this is basically the same question  to this post, the detailed answer is found here:

[CakePHP Increase Year Range in Drop Down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855451/cakephp-increase-year-range-in-drop-down/5855967#5855967)

Just modify the corresponding .ctp file that can be found in src/Template/tablename. (as of cakePHP 3.0.6)